# How can I pass setState function between contextProvider?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-hooks, next.js

I'm having some problems to set a state when repass the context provider for other elements, this is my code.
I'm creating a FancyboxContext for when i need it, i can call it anywhere.

```
import React, { createContext, useContext, useState } from 'react';

interface FancyboxContextInterface {
  fancybox: boolean;
  setFancybox(value: boolean): void;
}

interface FancyboxProviderProps {
  children: React.ReactNode;
}

interface UseFancyboxInterface {
  fancybox: boolean;
  setFancybox: React.Dispatch<React.SetStateAction<boolean>>;
}

const FancyboxInitialState = {
  fancybox: false,
  setFancybox: () => {}
};

const FancyboxContext = createContext<FancyboxContextInterface>(
  FancyboxInitialState
);

const FancyboxProvider: React.FC<FancyboxProviderProps> = ({
  children
}: FancyboxProviderProps) => {
  const [fancybox, setFancybox] = useState(FancyboxInitialState.fancybox);

  return (
    <FancyboxContext.Provider
      value={{
        fancybox,
        setFancybox
      }}
    >
      {children}
    </FancyboxContext.Provider>
  );
};

export const useFancybox = (): UseFancyboxInterface => {
  const context = useContext(FancyboxContext);
  const { fancybox, setFancybox } = context;

  return {
    fancybox,
    setFancybox
  };
};

export default FancyboxProvider;
```

involving _document.tsx in ContextProvider;

```
...
    render(): JSX.Element {
        return (
          <Html lang="pt">
            <Head>
              <link
                rel="stylesheet"
                href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Roboto:wght@300;400;700&display=swap"
              />
            </Head>
            <body>
              <FancyboxProvider>
                <Main />
              </FancyboxProvider>
              <NextScript />
            </body>
          </Html>
        );
      }
```

but when I am trying to start a simple call to setState(), nothing happens

```
import React, { useEffect } from 'react';
import { AppProps } from 'next/app';
import { useFancybox } from '../hooks/useFancybox';

import { Fancybox, GlobalStyles } from '../styles/global';

const myApp: React.FC<AppProps> = ({ Component, pageProps }) => {
  const { fancybox, setFancybox } = useFancybox();

  useEffect(() => setFancybox(true), []);

  return (
    <>
      {fancybox ? <Fancybox /> : ''}
      <Component {...pageProps} />
      <GlobalStyles />
    </>
  );
};

export default myApp;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, you should know that React Context can only be used on the client side.

You cannot place your ContextProvider `in _document.js` because it only runs on the server side. in your `_app.js` you are exporting a javascript function `myApp`  instead of a React component `MyApp`.

What you can do is place your FancyProvider in `_app.js` and call your setState in any page

what your `_app.js` should looks like

```
import React from "react";
import { AppProps } from "next/app";
import { GlobalStyles } from "../styles/global";

const MyApp: React.FC<AppProps> = ({ Component, pageProps }) => {
  return (
    <FancyboxProvider>
      <Component {...pageProps} />
      <GlobalStyles />
    </FancyboxProvider>
  );
};

export default MyApp;
```

Now you can call your setState on  `/pages/index.js or any other page`

```
import { useEffect } from "react";
import { useFancybox } from "../hooks/useFancybox";
import { Fancybox } from "../styles/global";

export default function Home() {
  const { fancybox, setFancybox } = useFancybox();

  useEffect(() => {
    setFancybox(true);
  }, []);

  return (
    <div>
      {fancybox ? <Fancybox /> : ""}
    </div>
  );
}
```